# How can I change css on rails activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have found a couple of similar questions but not a clear answer. 
I have install active admin and trying to change the css I read on the active_admin.css.scss

// To view the variables that Active Admin provides, take a look at
   // `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss` in the
   // Active Admin source.

I can't find the above file stylesheets/active_admin what am I missing ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking in the gem directory, e.g.,

```
$ cd `bundle show activeadmin`
```

Running `find` here shows (just a partial listing):

```
➜  activeadmin-0.6.0  find . -name "*.scss"
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.css.scss
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_forms.css.scss
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_header.css.scss
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_mixins.css.scss
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_typography.css.scss
... etc ...
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_typography.scss
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_utilities.scss
./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss
... etc ...
```

Those are the styles you can override.

Then however you're loading your CSS, for example:

```
➜  cat app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
@import 'active_admin_custom';
@import 'bootstrap_and_overrides';
```

Throw your overrides/customizations in there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add anything you need use as an override to app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/base.css.scss